Unable to get Spring `@Async` to run on dedicated threadpool
I was expecting the below code to spend 1 second in the below test, but it takes 5 seconds. I ran it by ChatGPT and it found no issues either. What could be the issue preventing Spring from running each invocation of the Future returning method on different threads?
@SpringJUnitConfig(SpringAsyncTest.MyTestConfig::class)
class SpringAsyncTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var sut: MySpecialBean

    @TestConfiguration()
    class MyTestConfig {
        @Bean(name = ["myThreadPoolExecutor"])
        fun asyncExecutor(): ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
            val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()
            executor.corePoolSize = 10
            executor.queueCapacity = 2000
            executor.initialize()
            return executor
        }

        @Bean
        fun sut(): MySpecialBean = MySpecialBean()
    }
    @Test
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class, ExecutionException::class)
    fun testSpringAsync() {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
            sut.aFutureCompletable(),
            sut.aFutureCompletable(),
            sut.aFutureCompletable(),
            sut.aFutureCompletable(),
            sut.aFutureCompletable()
        ).get()
     }
}

SUT
@Component
class MySpecialBean {

    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    @Async("myThreadPoolExecutor") // Use the custom executor
    fun aFutureCompletable(): CompletableFuture<Void?> {
        Thread.sleep(1000)  // Simulate a long-running task
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
    }
}

Reproduction
All the code is in a Gradle project that can be cloned here:
github.com/fatso83/test-driven-learning/.

You aren't using Spring Boot to run the test, so basically it renders the @Async useless. You will need an @EnableAsync on your configuration.

@M.Deinum Thanks for that elaboration. Actually the Spring Boot bit did not matter. I added the @SpringBootTest annotation without any difference. I was actually just wondering about the Spring specifics here, but wrote "Spring Boot" for whatever reason instead of Spring. The @EnableAsync was the missing bit. Pushed the fix to the repo.

M. Deinum answered the why in the comments section. For the @Async annotation to work one needs to instruct Spring to start processing it. You do this by adding the @EnableAsync to the configuration.
Before: 5 secs

After: 1 sec

